# FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly RestSharp dll

Tags: c#, dll, restsharp

I have implemented a plugin for a document application (Arxivar), the plugin (the dll) is called in the Arxivar's workflow, my plugin foresees the call to an API Rest using RestSharp, in generating the plugin for Arxivar I included the plugin dlls and that of RestSharp generated by the Solution build, once the workflow is started the error "FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly" related to the RestSharp dll is logged, it seems as if the dll was not found where it expects it
This is the property of the reference

[image]

Did I get any options wrong?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET?

Comment: .Net Framework 3.5